# The max_wall_time and max_cpu_time in ipopt are not working?

Tags: nonlinear-programming, nonconvex-programming, ipopt

The **max_wall_time** and **max_cpu_time** are not working in ipopt (cyipopt).

See example:

```
nlp = cyipopt.Problem(n=len(x0), m=len(cl), problem_obj=HS071(),
                      lb=lb, ub=ub, cl=cl, cu=cu)
```

The following are not working:

```
nlp.add_option('max_wall_time', 20)

nlp.add_option('max_cpu_time', 20)
```

it says `TypeError: Error while assigning an option.`

Any idea about how to set these stopping criteria in ipopt (cyipopt)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is shown below. I just figured that out, so I thought it would be better to leave the question that might be helpful for others.

It accepts float rather than integer!

nlp.add_option('max_wall_time', **20.0**)

nlp.add_option('max_cpu_time', **20.0**)

Comment: The [ipopt docs](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html) lists all available options including their type (float (real), integer or string).